# set_exception_handler not working

Tags: php, exception

I'm currently working on a small site that has custom error handling (Or, rather error *visualization*) and I'm having an issue with a certain function that involves both error and exception catching.

So, I have this code:

```
<?

$query = SQL::Query("SELECT * FROM sitevars");

if ( !$query )
{
    Kernel::Log('Could not retrieve sitevars.', 3, true);
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, it is supposed to use the `Kernel::Log` method if the query is false the `Kernel::Log` block that takes care of launching an exception if the third argument is equal to true is written as follows:

```
<?

if ( $kill )
{
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    $caller = array_shift($backtrace);

    echo "test";

    throw new Exception($message." near line ".$caller['line']." on file ".$caller['file']);
}
```

Now, the issue is that, even though `test` is printed, the exception handler is **not** called. I set the exception handler on the `__construct` method of the `Kernel` class

```
<?

public function __construct()
{
    global $config;

    self::$modList = array('Kernel');

    spl_autoload_register('Kernel::LoadModule');
    register_shutdown_function('Kernel::Shutdown');

    set_exception_handler('Kernel::Exception');     
    set_error_handler('Kernel::Error', E_ALL);
}
```

Now, I've triggered errors on other files, so I know that at least the error handler is working, but, even though I've executed `throw new Exception('test')` on various files, none of the exceptions are caught.

Why could this be happening?

Comment: Shouldn't `set_exception_handler('Kernel::Exception');` be `set_exception_handler(array("Kernel", "Exception"));`

Comment: Well as far as I know since PHP 5.3 Class::Method should be enough, however, I have tried it but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: You're right `Class:Method` should be enough.